# TemplateField, ItemTemplate and EditItemTemplte in dynamic gridview in C#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic

I am trying to write templatefield, itemtemplate and EditItemTemplate in Dynamic gridview. But I am not yet all getting any idea.

```
                TemplateField tf = new TemplateField();
                tf.HeaderText = "Product ID";
                tf.ItemTemplate=
```

Comment: Including this question you have eight questions requesting urgent answers - this is not a great way to address volunteers. Please be aware that your questions are not more important than others here, and that readers who help will answer questions at their leisure. With regret, downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

after adding your field you can define its contnent in RowDataBound

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TextBox txtProduct = new TextBox();
        txtProduct.ID = "txtProduct";
        txtProduct.Text = (e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row["Product"].ToString();
        e.Row.Cells[1].Controls.Add(txtProduct);
        //Cells[1] IS YOUR TEMPLATE CELL
    }
}
```

and for other type of row for example header and footer do the same way

Comment: It is working fine. But what actually I want is when i click on Edit button it will show in edit mode other wise it will show in normal boundfield how can i do it

Comment: ok, ithink you are looking for this: [CREATING DYNAMIC TEMPLATE FIELDS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.templatefield(v=vs.110).aspx)